# Arcmap adds vertices to shapefile at dataframe extent?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, polygon, editing, vertices

I'm running arcmap 10.4.1 trying to make a simple outline from a polygon shapefile. Should be a piece of cake, but a small part of the polygon extends off past the dataframe at the default projection. When I reproject with a 180° central meridian to get the entire thing in one piece, arcmap creates a vertical line where the polygon crossed the dataframe by adding extra vertices.

[image]

I can edit these vertices normally such that the line should disappear, but as soon as I deselect the polygon (before I can even save edits) it adds the extra vertices back in!

[image]

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: in what coordinate system is your polygon ? Did you also change the central meridian of the data or only of the dataframe ?

Comment: Does this link help? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/what-happens-to-features-at-180-dateline-.htm

Comment: That link is very helpful, thanks. The data uses GCS_Mercury (a Plate_Carree projection) and I did only change the meridian of the dataframe. I'll see what can be done about reprojecting the data itself.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.